# How to make both the Chinese and English characters the same font and style in the following template? ("张三" and other English characters)

Tags: xetex, templates, chinese, english

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Random Stuff %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{-3.0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{-1pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.6in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.19in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.7in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.4in}
\urlstyle{same}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-7pt}\scshape\raggedright\large\bfseries
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{0pt}]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Commands  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
  \item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-3pt}}
  }
}
\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-3pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & \textbf{\small #2} \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}
\newcommand{\resumeSubheadingContinue}[2]{
  \vspace{-3pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}
\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
  \vspace{-3pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & \textbf{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}
\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{0pt}}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}
\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.0in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{0pt}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        % NAME
        {\Huge\scshape 张三} 
        % SUBHEADING
        \\
        \vspace{0.15cm}
        {\raisebox{-0.2\height}{\faPhone}
        {}}
        \vline ~
        % EMAIL
        \href{}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}{\faEnvelope}  \underline{}}
        \vline ~
        % LINKEDIN
        \href{}
        {\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faLinkedin\ \underline{LinkedIn}}
        \vline ~
        % GITHUB
        \href{}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faGithub\ \underline{GitHub}}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean about Chinese and English in the *same* font.

Comment: @egreg if you compare the outputs of "张三" with "zhangsan", you will see they are very different - "张三" is much larger than the English version.

Comment: So likely you want to know how to scale one or other of the fonts to match the size of the other, rather than how to use the same font?

Comment: @cfr yah if that works. You can copy and paste this and try it yourself on overleaf to get what I meant, (in XeLatex mode btw)

Comment: That's because you're using `\scshape`.

Comment: @Stephen so what should i use instead?